# Compiling with -m32 yields "Exec format error"

Tags: linux, gcc

I am running 64 bit Arch Linux on an x86_64 bit processor. I compiled the kernel from source because I have some hardware that required a kernel patch. I have a simple test program, main.c:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("alsfdjadfslkajsdflkafj");
}
```

When I compile with the -m32 flag and run the program

```
gcc -m32 main.c -o main
./main
```

I get the following output: "cannot execute binary file: Exec format error".
I have the multilib packages installed for gcc. When I run `objdump -d main` The top of the file says "main:     file format elf32-i386". Is this correct? I think it should say i686 but I'm not sure. If it is correct, where can I start troubleshooting to solve this error?

Comment: Does your kernel support 32-bit executables?

Comment: @melpomene I was checking that. I couldn't find the option with nconfig. Can you give me its name? Sorry, I'm a bit of a newbie when it comes to kernel-hacking.

Comment: ISTM this is indeed coming from the kernel. From taking a look at `linux/fs/binfmt_elf.c` (grep for `ENOEXEC`) the only reasonable hypothesis I could come up with so far is that it might have something to do with the program interpreter. Could you post the output of `readelf -lW ./main | grep -A1 INTERP` ? Also, what does `ldd ./main` say? Another thing that might be helpful is running `LD_DEBUG=all ./main`